# Value between 2 column range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with a name, `lovalue`, `hivalue`. 
I want to pass a number and then let the table deduct what name to return.

For example:

```
Name, Low, High
Black,  0,   10
Grey,  11,   20
White, 21,   30
```

If the number 11 is passed the query returns Black.
If the number 22 is passed the query returns White.

Comment: what if 20 is passes?

Comment: I guess 11 -> black is a typo?

Comment: If the number 11 is passed the query returns Black.   
Is this a typo or is there some hidden logic here?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that it's a typo in your question when you say *...If the number 11 is passed the query returns Black...* you can do this

```
SELECT name
  FROM Table1
 WHERE 11 BETWEEN low AND high
```

Output:

```
| NAME |
--------
| Grey |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94c20/1)** demo

Comment: @user2430812 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @VALUE INT
SET @VALUE = 11

SELECT
    Name
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE @VALUE >= (Low + 1) AND  @VALUE <= (High + 1)
```

If it is a typo then use this:

```
DECLARE @VALUE INT
SET @VALUE = 11

SELECT
   Name
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE @VALUE >= Low AND  @VALUE <= High
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Parameter INT = 15 

SELECT NAME 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  LOW <= @Parameter 
       AND HIGH >= @Parameter
```

Comment: it will return grey for value 11 but OP wants black